# Vue 3/Vuetify - Access to a composable data in props defineDefault

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I have a component used on alot of page. And I actually have props inside with default values.

But my problem is, I would like to access to a composable data (useTheme from vuetify) inside the "withDefaults".

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useTheme } from 'vuetify'

const theme = useTheme()

interface Props {
  title: string
  color?: string
}

withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  color() {
    console.log(theme.global.name.value) <------ HERE

    return 'black'
  },
})
</script>
```

When I do that, I have an error saying:

> `defineProps()` in  cannot reference locally declared
> variables because it will be hoisted outside of the setup() function.
> If your component options require initialization in the module scope,
> use a separate normal  to export the options instead.

But if I make a second script, I can now use some refs inside the default props function, but I can't use value from a composable. Because if I wanna use a composable in the other script, I have to use 'Setup'. But I can't use Setup 2x times.

I could just pass as props the theme value but I think it will just remove the benefit by using composables.

Comment: EDIT: fixed with a computed

Comment: you can also decalre const theme = useTheme() in your defineprops inside color()

Comment: @PouyaM you are also right, thanks!

Comment: @PouyaM color() is not guaranteed to run at the time when composables are allowed to be used.

Comment: @Jer Consider extracting the solution to the answer if it suits you, otherwise the question appears as unanswered to other users

Comment: Please don't add answers to the question. Post an answer instead.

Comment: hi @BDL didn't get how to mark as resolved when I resolved myself. I've searched and it says that I have to make a new answer, then wait for 6 hour and mark it as resolved, do you have any other tip? thanks

Comment: @Jer: This is exactly how it's supposed to work. You post an answer and after 6h you can accept it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT: Fixed with a computed:

```
<script setup lang="ts"> import { ref, computed } from 'vue' import { useTheme } from 'vuetify'

const theme = useTheme()

const defaultColor = computed(() => {   return theme.global.name.value
=== 'DarkTheme' ? 'red' : props.color })

interface Props {   title: string   color?: string }

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {   color() {
    return 'black'   }, })

</script>
```